# Prevent body scrolling on mousewheel if input[type=number] are focused

Tags: html, css

How to prevent page scrolling on mousewheel when input[type=number] are focused?

I want the page stay fixed and the number spin up/down.

I would like some ideas on how to implement this in a single shot in angularjs. Preferably without modifying the HTML.

edit:

this happens only if angularstrap is loaded. only bootstrap works fine.

Comment: Do you want to disable input scrolling (which is what the post you linked is describing), or do you want to disable page scrolling?

Comment: I want the page stay fixed and the number spin up/down.